# Retriving data from the internet blocks main thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to write an Android app which will retrieve the data from internet and save in a local file. This is what I have written:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateData();
        }
    };
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.post(r);
}
private Boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(ni != null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void updateData() {
    if(!isOnline()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to update data: Internet Connection Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet req = new HttpGet("***SOME URL****");
            HttpResponse res = client.execute(req);             
            InputStream is = res.getEntity().getContent();
            InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(is);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Boolean end = false;
            do {
                int t = ir.read();
                if(t==-1) {
                    end = true;
                }
                else {
                    sb.append((char)t);
                }
            }
            while(!end);
            String s = sb.toString();
            File f = new File(getFilesDir(), "data.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
            fw.write(s);
            fw.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the main thread blocked for about 2-3 seconds. And I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this. So if you think this is an incorrect way to do, feel free to tell me.

Regards,
Sarun

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

Comment: make your web service call in a worker thread. Not in the main UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From handler Constructor [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler%28%29):

> associates this handler with the Looper for the current thread.

This means that the `Handler` you created is associated with the `Looper` of the UI thread, which means that the `runnable` is being executed on the UI thread (therefore you see the pause of the UI).
I suggest that you will use Android's `AsyncTask` or instantiate the `Handler` on a background thread.

Comment: @SarunIntaralawan The AsyncTask acts as a managed thread that can separate background tasks from UI tasks in a meaningful manner and breaks up the code into respectable components that are easier to follow and understand.  It's extremely useful to get used to using them.

Comment: @SarunIntaralawan AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. it allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers (It uses an inner thread pool).
See more at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask, to get rid of this. 
The code of AsyncTask is below:

```
class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MyTopic.this);

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


            return msg;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {

                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }

        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.setMessage("Fetching...Topic List!!!");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();

        }
    }
```

calling code:

```
AsyncLogin as = new AsyncLogin();
as.execute();
```